# ¿Deberia de cambiar de compilador?

Tags: c++, vscode

He estado peleando durante días con el compilador MSY2, porque compila mis mini programas,pero lo hace de manera extraña, cabe resaltar que soy nuevo en esto.

Sucede que, cuando trato de usar cualquier función para obtener la entrada de una cadena que quiero usar, salta a la siguiente línea de código, es decir, no tengo el tiempo de escribirla, he intentado limpiar el búfer y todo.

Pero funciona muy mal cuando intento ingresar letras.

¿Debo reinstalarlo o cambiar a otro entorno?

Lo curioso es que en Devc ++, con otro compilador, el programa funciona perfectamente, pero en Vscode me da errores en todas partes cuando usa una cadena o alguna entrada de letras como me doy cuenta.

He intentado limpiar el búfer con diferentes funciones, pero como veo que no hace ninguna diferencia, no se que hacer.
he probado con cin.ignore, cin.clear, fflush(stdin), de todo,pero nada que funciona, guarda los strings como le da la gana.

adjunto codigo con la estructura en cuestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


struct personas{
    string nombre;
    bool discapacidad;
};

void meterPaciente(personas[],personas[]);
void mostrarLista(personas[],personas[]);
void inicio(personas[],personas[]);

int tamF = 0;
int tamV = 0;
int main(){
personas verdadero[20];
personas falso[20];
inicio(verdadero,falso);

    return 0;
}

void inicio(personas verdadero[],personas falso[]){

int opc;
char key;
do{
cout<<"||Bienvenido||\n1-.Introducir paciente.\n2-.Mostrar lista.\nOpcion:";cin>>opc;cout<<endl;
switch (opc){
    case 1: meterPaciente(verdadero,falso);break;
    case 2: mostrarLista(verdadero,falso);break;
}
fflush(stdin);
cout<<"\nDesea seguir utilizando el programa (S/N)?:";cin>>key;
system("pause");
system("cls");
}while (key != 'n' && 'N');
}





void meterPaciente(personas verdadero[],personas falso[]){
    int temp;
      cout<<"\nEl paciente padece de alguna discapacidad?: (1-.SI/ 0-.NO):";cin>>temp;

    if (temp == 0){
       falso[tamF].discapacidad = temp;
cin.get();
      cout<<"\nIntroduzca el nombre de el paciente:";getline(cin,falso[tamF].nombre);
      tamF++;
    }

    if (temp == 1){
        verdadero[tamV].discapacidad = temp;
cin.get();
      cout<<"\nIntroduzca el nombre de el paciente:";getline(cin,verdadero[tamV].nombre);
      tamV++;
   
    }

}






void mostrarLista(personas verdadero[],personas falso[]){

int i,j;

cout<<"\n\nLista de clientes sin discapacidad.";
for(i = 0; i < tamF;i++){
cout<<endl<<falso[i].nombre;
}


cout<<"\n\nLista de Discapacitados.";
for(j = 0; j < tamV;j++){
cout<<endl<<verdadero[j].nombre;
}
}
```

Lo parezca o no, probe con getline nadamas utilizando un string y no un vector char, e igualmente hizo la misma gracia.

[image: Esto es lo que hace]

Comment: Recuerdo haber visto una pregunta parecida hace algunos días. La respuesta es NO. El problema es que cada vez que la consola necesita interacción debes presionar ENTER. Esto escribe un salto de línea que el operador `>>` no consume. Si solo utilizas el operador `>>` no notas ningún problema ya que ignora el espacio en blanco anterior al token. En cambio, `getline` lee hasta encontrar un salto de línea. Entonces `getline` se encuentra con el salto de línea que quedó luego de utilizar el operador `>>`, no pide que ingreses más caracteres y obtienes una cadena vacía.

Comment: Por regla general, para solucionarlo debes usar `cin.ignore()` antes de un `get()` o `getline()` solo si la última vez que obtuviste cualquier entrada fue mediante el operador `>>`.

Comment: esta es una opinion aparte. msys2 es un runtime para ejecutar linux el compilador es mingw que esta hecho en base a ingenieria inversa de la api win32. es un cross compiler que se debe usar en situaciones muy especificas como portar programas de otras plataformas con librerias como wxwidgets o qt.. te recomiendo usar gcc en WSL o MSVC si te gusta lo nativo. Evita usar CodeBlocks o DevC++ porque vienen de epocas antiguas cuando cobraban por compiladores. Estos vienen con mingw(era el unico gratuito) y esta en una version muy antigua llenos de bugs.